# O que é mais aconselhável? Realizar a consulta através de uma lista ou diretamente no banco de dados?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, linq

Eu tenho que realizar uma consulta onde preciso fazer 4 `INNER JOIN` e ainda usar `WHERE` em  vários campos.

O que é mais aconselhável?

1. Realizar a consulta dessa forma?

```
using (DbContexto db = new DbContexto())
{
    var query = (from t1 in db.tabela1
                 join t2 in db.tabela2 on t1.id equals t2.fk_t1
                 join t3 in db.tabela3 on t1.idt3 equals t3.fk_t1
                 where (t1.v1 = 1) && (t2.v2 = 2) && (t3.v3 = 3)
                 select t1
             );
}
```

2. Ou dessa?

```
List listaTabela1 = new List();
List listaTabela2 = new List();
List listaTabela3 = new List();

using (DbContexto db = new DbContexto())
{
    listaTabela1 = (from t1 in db.tabela1 select t1).ToList();
    listaTabela2 = (from t2 in db.tabela2 select t2).ToList();
    listaTabela3 = (from t3 in db.tabela3 select t3).ToList();
    var query    = (from t1 in listaTabela1 
                    join t2 in listaTabela2 on t1.id equals t2.fk_t1
                    join t3 in listaTabela3 on t1.idt3 equals t3.fk_t1
                    where (t1.v1 = 1) && (t2.v2 = 2) && (t3.v3 = 3)
                    select t1
                   );
}
```

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54629/discussion-on-question-by-wb80-o-que-e-mais-aconselhavel-realizar-a-consulta-at)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A forma mais aconselhável depende do seu objetivo final com o código. Apenas pelo texto ao redor do código seria fácil descartar a pergunta como dependente de opinião. Ao observar com mais cuidado as duas alternativas, porém, creio que a primeira é mais aconselhável.

O motivo é o seguinte: na primeira forma, você executará uma única consulta no banco para obter os dados que deseja. O servidor é capaz de criar uma estratégia de busca bem definida e, se tudo estiver OK do lado do SQL, retorna de forma eficiente o que você quer.

Já na segunda opção você tem três consultas ao banco sem critério de filtragem algum. O conteúdo completo das tabelas vai ser lido no disco, alocado na memória do servidor do banco de dados, depois vai para o espaço de memória da sua aplicação e por fim você descarta o que não quer. Toda vez que o resultado da sua busca não contiver todos os registros das três tabelas, você terá feito operações, bem... Por falta de palavra melhor, operações inúteis.

Note ainda que a complexidade dos seus joins deve ser algo de forma aproximada de um algoritmo O(n^m^o). Em língua de gente, isso significa que o tempo de execução do seu programa não cresce de forma proporcional a quantidade de dados envolvidos... O crescimento do tempo de execução é **exponencial**, e pode ser proporcional ao cubo da quantidade de elementos com os quais vai trabalhar (pode ser até pior que isso). Na verdade estou vendo dois *inner joins* em seu exemplo - com quatro *inner joins*, estamos conversando sobre a quinta potência. É essencial otimizar para que o mínimo de elementos seja obtido da base de dados.

Fique com a primeira opção, a menos que queira aproveitar os itens que não façam parte do resultado da query para outra coisa.